# Real Time Clock Module Reset

Tags: arduino-leonardo, rtc

I just had a pretty simple question about the RTC Clock Modules, more specifically the DS3231 RTC. Once calibrated and running on my Arduino if I were to unplug it and plug it back in, will the time and everything reset and require another calibration, or will it work like a computer that, even when reset, retains the correct time and date. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends if your module has a battery backup or not. A bare chip, by itself, will loose everything. That's why many breakout boards will have a small lithium cell on them to retain everything when the power is removed.

Comment: So it will be attatched to a breadboard and then attatched to the Arduino. If the main power supply to the Arduino, which is a external 5V battery source, you are saying it would be wise to also have another backup source just in case?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on your module. If you are building it from components, then yes you should provide a battery backup - like it shows you in the datasheet.

Comment: [This is the module I will be using](http://www.miniinthebox.com/nl/ds3231-high-precision-real-time-clock-module-blauw-3-3-5-5v_p680551.html?currency=EUR&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&adword_mt=&adword_ct=73332089922&adword_kw=&adword_pos=1o2&adword_pl=&adword_net=g&adword_tar=&adw_src_id=4196617767_313304202_22460844882_pla-157330368522&gclid=CjwKEAjw_LG8BRDb1JTxm8uP_UwSJADu_8pW1Q1Q_7RWUPlYjFk6ECejrlkHkkSuVT6uY_j8VkwTJRoCx0Dw_wcB)

Comment: That is what you have? Do you know what that big round silver thing is in the picture?

Comment: Brilliant. Sorry, long day. Thanks for the help.